# Is it possible to call .NET Invoke method from SilkTest test case?

Tags: .net, silktest

Is it possible to call .NET Invoke method from SilkTest test case?
I can call it using `DynamicInvoke` method, but I don't know what to pass as parameters that would be equal to method delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to call methods with `DynamicInvoke` that require arguments that can't be represented by Silk Test's types or offer a simple constructor which can be auto-detected (default constructor, or constructor taking a `String` argument).

That being said, there might be solutions to your issue:

- If you have access to the application's code, you can add a method to the UI element that does whatever you intend to do with the `Invoke` call, and call that wrapper method instead
- With the upcoming Silk Test 14 release, you have the option to `DynamicInvoke` arbitrary static methods in you application, which again can be used as a wrapper around `Invoke`.
- Also with Silk Test 14, you'll be able to load custom assemblies and call methods there, so if you don't want to pollute your application with functionality for testing, put that in a custom assembly and load it for your tests.

Comment: I need to call method get_Item that has two overloads - one accepts string and another int as paramater. Is it possible to force DynamicInvoke to use int overload - now it always uses string overload and it's not working properly?

Comment: Make sure that in your test script the parameter is an `Int`, then it should pick the correct overload.

Comment: I've declared the parameter as integer iPar, and then passed it to DynamicInvokeMethods, but it doesn't work (string overload always gets called).